# Service continues to run, but button state changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a data table and in each row of the table I have a column with buttons. In order to execute only the button of the line where it was clicked, in the start / pause timer function, I pass the index of that line so that only the button of that line is executed.

I developed the functions in a service so that when changing pages the timer continues to work and not be destroyed.

My problem is that when I run the timer and when I change the page, the button state changes, that is I click play, it turns green, when I change the page and back to confirm the button state it is not green . I think my problem is that it loses the line index when I change the page, because the service continues to work.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

**HTML**

```
            <div class="row">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn ClassPlay">                  
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
                  (click)="currentState='start'; startTimer(data)">Start</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" routerLinkActive="active"
                  (click)="currentState='pause'; pauseTimer(data)">Stop</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: how are you coming back to the page, using browsers back button or clicking on a _**a href**_ or angular route?

Comment: @VipulDessai To come back : routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/note']" and when I leave the page: (click)="route.navigate(['/home'])"

Comment: store all of the data which is connected with the timer in your service, it will be solve the problem

Comment: @Ashot Aleqsanyan  How? I don't understand what I have to do :(

Comment: Please include your component ts file to the question I will create the stackblitz example

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I already added the Component. Thanks for your help !

Comment: you need to show more of your component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example, Please check the link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xn5gvl

What I did.

1. Remove the trasform method from service and added date pipe for show the time in format `'HH:mm:ss'`
2. move the `currentRowIndex` property into service
3. made the service as public for use it into template like this `taskService.method()` or `taskService.property`
4. added `clearIntervale` into `service.startTimer()`
5. changed the `startTimer()` and `pauseTimer()` in `component.ts`
6. **Please note you need to replace `*ngFor="let data of datas"` with `*dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate'"` and the images too**

Comment: I am applying this to several tables and using pagination buttons (I click on button 2 and hide table 1 and show it to 2). The problem is that when you start the button in row 1 of table 1 ... when you switch tables ... the button of row 1 of this new open table is also started. It's because of rowIndex, but I don't know how I can fix it :(

Comment: @MikeLanders Hello, sorry I don't understand can you clarify your question? or please change the existing stackblitz example for reproduce the issue.